# SEO friendly URL with using one variable each language

Tags: variables, url, seo

I have the follow situation:

Our actual URL are follow structured:

http://www.silentdivers.com/index.php?lang=en for english, fr for french, ge fr german

Now I like to have - or I nned Your advise what is the best way:

http://www.silentdivers.com/de/ for index.php in german

And so on.

I need help how to do this in a htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule (in .htaccess) would have to look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]{2})/$  /index.php?lang=$1
```

- `^/` means starts with slash
- `([a-z]{2})` is two lower case letters (the language code) surrounded in quotes to capture them as `$1`
- `/$` is "ends in slash"
- It gets internally rewritten to your index.php script with a lang param

You could add another rule to handle other files for which you want to do this.   For example this will make `/en/discoverscubadiver` work by forwarding it to `discoverscubadiver.php?lang=en`:

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)$  /$2.php?lang=$1
```

Comment: Hi Stephen

And like this, I need to do for each site/file I have? eg

If I have

http://www.silentdivers.com/discoverscubadiver.php?lang=en

and I like to get

http://www.silentdivers.com/en/discoverscubadiver/

What i need to do?

Comment: I have updated my answer to add an additional rule that will work with other files.

Comment: Hi
I tried now the last few weeks to work it out. But no solution. I have the follow things now:


This is my htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteEngine  on

RewriteRule    ^/([a-z]{2})/$  /index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule    ^/([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)$  /$2.php?lang=$1

Then I tried to to the follow:

[link](http://easy.turtlesdive.com/ru/)

Get the 404 error.

Comment: `RewriteEngine` needs to come before any `RewriteCond` or `RewriteRule`.  If you are doing this in .htaccess your rewrite rules should not start with a `/` because that is assumed in that context.  I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: Okay, thank You. I changed some more things, but it works now as I need it.